# test java applet is getting started in windows 7 even after successful install of JRE 7 update 9 in IE9

Tags: java, applet, java-7, classnotfoundexception, ioexception

I am getting following exceptions while testing my java installation, even after I reinstalled JRE and Internet Explorer 9 several times. Please help me.

I am testing my jre installation through [www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp).

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: testJava2_1.TestVMApplet.class
```

Comment: Java 7 update 9 in FF on Windows 7 brings up the test applet OK.  Is it just IE there, do other browsers load the page OK?

Answer (score 1):

Your Java installation is fine as you are recieving Java errors and such.

> java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response

Java IO exceptions (Input/output) are thrown when the program can't read or write which includes obtaining the applet you are trying to run. In this case it is being thrown because it can't be downloaded and read, this is most likely due to a network fault or security setting.